# I am trying to add a new field to the default Django Form and am getting an error when I'm trying to import a class from a forms.py file I made

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

The error is occurring in views.py file in which when I try to import the form class I made from my forms .py file I get an error of...

```
Import ".forms" could not be resolved
```

Here is what my views.py file looks like:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegisterForm
# Create your views here.

def register(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return redirect("/home")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render(response,"register/register.html",{"form":form})
```

And here is my forms.py file

```
    from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta: 
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]
```

Why am I getting that error/what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem comes from importing "from django.contrib.auth import forms" so i figure out that when you comment it out or just delete it, everything should work fine!.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
# This is where your problem stems "from django.contrib.auth import forms"
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta: 
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]
```

Well in your view the conditional statement wasn't meeting the condition after the form is saved and so it wouldn't redirect to the home page, you needed to put the redirect right below the form.save() for it to meet the condition as in  what i have done.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("/home")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render(request,"register/register.html",{"form":form})
```

Comment: Tried that and am still having the same problem, when I click register on the Django registration form I imported it's not changing the page. Though removing it didn't do anything bad so it definitely helped.

Comment: The reason  why it does not redirect is that when after the condition test pass the saving form.save() of registered user the redirect should be just right below the conditional statement for it to redirect to the home page but with what you did it  wasn't meeting the conditional test and so it wont redirect, but i have made that correction  , so it should work now.

Comment: Thank you, I have got it to work.

Comment: You are welcome!